# Throwing Objects Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm creating a 2D sidescroller with my own graphics. I've put the main character into Blender and created a few animations resulting in a number of sprites containing the whole character in different poses, and I switch them one by one. Now I want to make it possible for the player to pick up an object (let's say an axe) and throw it. I want the axe to held in hand, meaning it would follow the hand's position. But as there is only one sprite there's no hand's position. The only idea I came up with is to create a new set of sprites with the character holding the axe. Then I would play the "Throw" animation and only after it's been finished I would create an object of an axe and attach a script that would move it further. But my intuition tells me it's too big a workaround  and in the end it's going to produce more problems than it would fix. Have you got an idea how this could be managed in a professional way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say store your sprites in a custom format that records the positions of important parts, e.g. the hand.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on the topic? I have absolutely no idea how to create my own format. Do you mean a format inside Unity? And what kind of format basically? Like a .png?

Comment: You store individual frames of the sprite animation as separate images, right? Well for each of those frames I propose that you also store a list of positions for e.g. hands. To compute those positions, an "easy" (almost no math involved) way of doing so is to make a small object and attach them to each hand, render *only* them, and use an external program to search for their positions in the rendered frames.

Comment: Let's say we have a list of hands' positions in each of the frames. Apart from location, they change their rotation as well, and the axe has to rotate at the same angle. How am I supposed to find those rotations?

Comment: I see. In that case, you will need to track the *entire skeleton*. By that I mean all joints and all control points / rods of the rig. e.g. for the hand you must have an extended bone from the wrist; put an object on the end of that  bone to keep track of hand rotations. This is assuming that you only allow rotations in the viewing plane.

Comment: In that case, skeletal animation is needed and you can check out this tool provided by unity: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/79840